# Compare these two numerical analysis books ? Kincaid vs Quarteroni

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I am considering to buy a reference books for using along side with my professors' notes in the graduate level numerical analysis. Which one is better ?

[Quarteroni's Numerical Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540346589)

[Kincaid's Numerical analysis : Mathematics of Scientific computing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847880)

Comment: Analysis of Numerical Methods (Dover Books on Mathematics), 
Eugene Isaacson, Herbert Bishop Keller. I have the Kincaid book and never look at it. To be fair, mine is one revision old, but doubtful it has changed much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Kincaid, but I have been using Quarteroni. I would say that it is useful as a  fairly comprehensive reference, but it doesn't do a particularly good job of introducing a technique to the uninitiated.

If you're looking for a book that has a clear explanation when your professor's notes might be difficult to understand, this is not that book.  If, on the other hand, you're interested in seeing alternative approaches, applications, and extensions of techniques whose motivation and basic workings you understand, Quarteroni is not a bad choice.

Comment: I have heard many my upper classmen complaining about Quarteroni's book, I ask here cuz it is on the reference list of my professor. So do you have any recommendation ?

Comment: It really depends on you. Are you really excited about numerical mathematics? Do you see yourself needing a reference down the line, when you're finding solutions to some exotic PDE and the methods are familiar but not quite fresh on your mind? If so, go with Quarteroni. If you're not sure about numerical analysis and are just taking this class to test the waters or if you're not looking to get more out of this class than the professor explains, then don't make the investment. If I were in your situation, I would probably not buy it, but that's just me.

Comment: Here's a question to ask yourself: have you ever gotten a supplemental textbook for your course? What motivated you to crack it open and look through? Those characteristics are the characteristics of the book you should be getting.

Comment: My background in numerical analysis is fairly modest,- just one undergrad intro course. This is the first time I will take a graduate level course, thus I want a text that present the material in a friendly way, have lots of example and exercise.Judging from your answer, Quarteroni is more advance for my level. However I am not surprised since I am gonna take a advanced  course. That's why I need to find a book to fill the gap of my present knowledge and the graduate school contents.

Comment: My advice is then that Quarteroni is probably not right for you.  I wouldn't say that Quarteroni is necessarily more advanced than other texts, just that it prioritizes fitting material in over explaining it thoroughly/understandably.  The reviews I've read make Kincaid seem a lot more user-friendly.

Comment: How about this one ? http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Numerical-Methods-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486680290

Comment: Ah, yes, my Numerical professor directly recommended that one as a reference, and referred to it when proving a theorem regarding quadrature on periodic functions.  It is considered a classic.  I'm considering getting this myself now that you reminded me.  However, this again is (apparently) fairly dense, and might not be a great choice for an educational supplement.

Comment: You should see which if any of these books are available in your school's library.  You might be surprised.